# Error Delete row from php

Tags: php, html

i have a form that contain an input: mail
and i would like to delete row from my database when the value of the email exist in database
but its not working 
my HTML is

```
<form action="delete.php" method="post">
<h3>Email:</h3><input type="text" name="email" required/>
<input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

my PHP page is

```
<?php
include("connexion.php");
$email=$_POST['email'];
$req='DELETE FROM `personne` WHERE email="$email";';
if(mysql_query($req))
{
echo 'Delete with succes ';
}
else
echo 'error';
```

so it show me 'Delete with succes ' but when i check the DB nothing change

Comment: Your script is [prone to SQL injections](http://bobby-tables.com) and also [the mysql extension is deprecated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php). You should switch to [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) and use prepared statements.

Comment: thanks for your responses it was basic syntax error ' '
but i would like to understand why mysql_query($req) return true even when the request was wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In apostrophes enclosed string, $email is not replaced for `$email` variable.

Replace it for this

```
"DELETE FROM `personne` WHERE email='$email';";
```

`mysql_query($req)` returns true, because the query succeeded: it deleted zero rows. See [the reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

...and the resource was evaluated as true, since PHP is weakly typed language.

If you want to check how many rows were deleted, use `mysql_affected_rows()`. But since `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, I recommend to advance to [mysqli](https://www.php.net/mysqli).

Also carefully read TimWolla's comment to your answer. This time zero emails were deleted, but if you mess the condition a little, you may easily delete ALL records from personne table. You can make it a little less dangerous if you add `LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 2):

```
$req = "DELETE FROM personne
    WHERE   email = '" . $email . "';";
```

And please consider securing the email variable to avoid SQL injections and if possible, switch to PDO.

Regarding your answer (i can't add a comment, yet):

mysql_query returns a positive MySQL result resource to the query result, or FALSE on error. The function also returns TRUE/FALSE for INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE queries to indicate success/failure.

Since your query doesn't fail, the function returns true.

Answer (score 0):

Basic PHP syntax: `'`-quoted strings do NOT interpolate variables:

```
$req="DELETE FROM `personne` WHERE email='$email';";
```

Note the reversal of the `"` and `'` quotes. And note that you are vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)